# Linking Magento Admin Accounts with a Customer Account

Tags: magento, linked-list, admin

Does anyone know of an extension that will link a Magento admin account with a specific customer account?

Here's the scenario I'm trying to figure out:

- Store owner has 5 Sales Reps.
- Wants Sales Reps to be able to log into the admin panel as **admin users**.
- But also wants Sales Reps to have their own **customer account** so they can buy products from the store.

I've searched through Magento connect and cannot find anything that does this.  Anyone know of a way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, its possible to create orders through the backend. Go to Sales > Ordere and click "Create Order" in the top left.

Second of all, if you create customer usernames and passwords that are the same as on the Admin section, you could try to call `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->login($username, $password);` when an admin logs in. Haven't tried it though, but thats what happens in the `loginPostAction` of  `Mage_Customer_AccountController` [link](http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php).